# Determine N such that x> N, f (x)<x

Tags: number-theory

Let  $f$  be  the  function  from  the  set  of  positive  integers into  itself  which  associates  to  any  number  $x$  the  sum  $f(x)$  of  the squares  of  the  digits  in  $x$.  For  instance  $f(a_1a_2a_3\ldots a_n)=a_1^3+a_2^3+...+a_n^3$. Where  $x=a_1a_2a_3\ldots a_n$    is    a    $n$-digits  number.

Please how can I determine a number $N$ such that  if  $x>N$  then  $f(x)<x$.

I will really appreciate if anybody can give me a source to solve this problem

Comment: squares or cubes?

Comment: Have you proven that such an N will exist uniquely?

Comment: @Aniket Why "uniquely"?  If it's true for $N$ it's also true for $N+1$... and any higher value.

Comment: @ErickWong The question asks to "determine $\mathbf{a}$ number N ". Focus of my comment was to check whether he means the smallest possible $N$ by "a number".

Answer (score 1):

If $x$ has $n$ digits then $x \ge 10^{n-1}$ and $f(x) \le 9^3 n$ (your question confuses squares and cubes).

So if $n \ge 6$, i.e. $x \ge 100000$, then $x \gt f(x)$.

There are smaller possibilities too.

Answer (score 1):

Note that for any number $x$ with $n$ digits, the sum of cubes of the digits is upper bounded by $9^3 n = 729n$, and $n$ itself if upper bounded by $1 + \log_{10} x$.

So you want a $N$ s.t. $729 + 729\log_{10} N < N$. As $\log x$ grows slower than $x$, for any $x>N$, the relation will hold.

It's easy to see that $N = 10000$ is good enough.